# Django query many-to-many field

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have these two models.

```
class Tickets(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=12)
    recipients = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser)
    title = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(primary_key=True,)
    user_name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=20)
```

In Tickets model, recipients may include multiple users. 
I'm trying to 
1. Read how many tickets does specific user has. 
2. Regroup Tickets by recipients to get this kind of output in template.

```
user_name1
   Ticket.id
   Ticket.title
user_name2
   Ticket.id
   Ticket.title
user_name3
   Ticket.id
   Ticket.title
```

I was trying really hard on "regroup", but not much result...
Could someone give me some guidance?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get tickets of each user you could just use the reverse relation,

```
users = CustomUser.objects.all()
```

and in template,

```
{% for user in users %}
    {{ user.username }}
    {% for ticket in user.ticket_set.all %}
        {{ ticket.id }}
        {{ ticket.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: But if user1 is not in any ticket, your approach will show user1 with blank beneath it anyway, right?

Comment: @user2869934 that's why you have an if statement.

Comment: i'm adding this filter to template but not working. {% for t in user1.tasksticket_set.all|finished == False %} Do you have any idea?

Comment: If you don't want users with no tickets: right under the `{{ for user in users }}`, put `{{ if user.ticket_set }}` then close it right before the last `{% endfor %}`